# JS <---> PHP communication

Tags: php, javascript

I need to, using JS get some values returned by a PHP script.

How to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert PHP variables to JavaScript variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658858/how-do-i-convert-php-variables-to-javascript-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX: http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var string = <?php echo $variable; ?>;
</script>
```

or AJAX

Answer (score 1):

You can create a js file with PHP.

For exemple

```
// My script php
var js_var = '<?php echo "toto"?>';
```

or use an AJAX framework and JSON

Answer (score 1):

What's the method you're using to communicate with PHP? If you're using AJAX you might want to checkout jQuery or a library of some sort and use JSON for communication.

Using these methods, like using getJSON, you can easily access the variables returned by the PHP-script.

Please provide some more details to your question so we can answer your question in more detail and provide some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign php values to JavaScript like so:

```
var x = <?php echo $varible ; ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can use a XMLHttpRequest to access your PHP script. This is called AJAX.
I recommend you the JSON serialization method for the data you send & receive to / from the PHP script.