# Accessing multidimentional array from javascript to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php

Using javascript have added rows at run time.Have stored name of each column of a row in multidimentional array.Now I need to access this array on a PHP page.How to POST this array on PHP page?The below code is regarding the generating multidimentional array.

var j=0;
     function addRow(tableID)
     {
     j++;

```
 var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount=table.rows.length;
 var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
 var colCount=table.rows[0].cells.length;

alert(rowCount)

 for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++)
     {


 var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
 newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
 switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type)
     {case"text":newcell.childNodes[0].value="";
    // alert(2);
       var value = "" + "coll"+ j + i;

      newcell.setAttribute("name",value);
      MultiArray = new Array(rowCount)
      MultiArray [rowCount] = new Array(7)
     //var name  = newcell.getAttribute('name')

     MultiArray[rowCount][i]  = newcell.getAttribute('name')
     alert("hi")
    //alert(MultiArray[rowCount][i]);



     break;
     case"checkbox":newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;
     break;
     case"Remark":newcell.childNodes[0].textarea=0;
     break;
     }}}
```

Comment: Serialise as JSON and submit as an Ajax request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS <---> PHP communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964961/js-php-communication)

Comment: AJAX may well not be required here. Sending the array as JSON via a POST from the `<form>` submission would be enough in many cases. This could be done by listening for the `submit` event.